# Creating and importing dynamic module in python

Tags: python

I am trying to dynamically create and import a module which contain a single variable `x`

**CreateImportDynModule.py**

```
import sys
from types import ModuleType

print "1 --> __name__: ", __name__

dm = ModuleType(__name__) #create module with same name
dm.x = 5                  #add member x = 5

print "2 --> __name__: ", __name__
print "3 -->", sys.modules[__name__]

sys.modules[__name__] = dm  #replace this module with dm
                            #which have same name
                            ### Running CreateImportDynModuleDemo.py failes
                            #In debug, I realize that this screws
                            #__name__, setting it to NoneType
print "4 --> __name__: ", __name__
print "5 -->", sys.modules[__name__]
print "6 -->", sys.modules[__name__].x
```

**CreateImportDynModuleDemo.py**

```
import CreateImportDynModule as cidm
#print cidm.x  #I want this to work, but above import itself does not work and 
               #gives error stated below
```

Running CreateImportDynModule.py gives following correct output:

```
1 --> __name__:  __main__
2 --> __name__:  __main__
3 --> <module '__main__' from 'path/CreateImportDynModule.py'>
4 --> __name__:  __main__
5 --> <module '__main__' (built-in)>
6 --> 5
```

But, running CreateImportDynModuleDemo.py gives following error:

```
1 --> __name__:  CreateImportDynModule
2 --> __name__:  CreateImportDynModule
3 --> <module 'CreateImportDynModule' from 'path/CreateImportDynModule.py'>
4 --> __name__:  None
5 -->Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "path/CreateImportDynModuleDemo.py", line 10, in <module>
    import CreateImportDynModule as cidm
  File "path/CreateImportDynModule.py", line 18, in <module>
    print "5 -->", sys.modules[__name__]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

Line `sys.modules[__name__] = dm` sets `__name__` to `NoneType` as you can read in comments of CreateImportDynModule.py at three hashes `###`.
But why is this happening?

Comment: I can tell you that this works as expected under Python 3 (i.e. no lookup reset, all variables resolved) - I am guessing that in Python 2, the sys.modules reassignment during the module construction breaks some internal lookup.

Comment: Workaround: Make a function that executes `globs = globals().copy(); sys.modules[__name__] = dm; globals().update(globs)`

Comment: @matatoaster switching from python 2.7 to python 3.4 (and changing `print` to `print()`) fixed the things.